# Can a queue of pending transactions be confirmed if the last transaction is re-tried with a high gas price(assuming limit is met)?

Tags: transactions, gas, accounts, gas-price, pending-transactions

I have several pending transactions from the same account with a low gas price. What if I send one more transaction with next nonce but high gas price? Can it help to mine all pending transactions queue behind last "expensive" transaction?

Comment: No, it can't...

Answer (score 0):

No, it cannot. Miners will look at each individual transaction and decide whether or not that single transaction is profitable for them to include in a block. Future transactions don't affect current ones.

Comment: But miner can't include transaction in block if there are pending transactions with smaller nonce, am I right?

Comment: You are correct. The only instance where a miner can include this transaction in a block is if the transactions with lower nonces are in the same block as well.